# (c++) How can I get this to loop back to the menu? Calculator type

Tags: c++

I know this code is still sloppy but I'm currently focused on just getting it to do what I need it to before I make it pretty. My assignment is to make a calculator that gets the choice and the input, then carries out the operation, then loops back to the menu to prompt the user for another choice and input. I'm not exactly sure how to go about it without using global variables.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int showMenu(int & );
double getX(double & );
double getY(double & );
int add(double, double);
int divide(double, double);
int multiply(double, double);
int subtract(double, double);
bool exit(bool & );

int main(){
    int choice;
    bool yes = false;
    double x =0;
    double y =0;
    do{
        showMenu(choice);
        getX(x);
        getY(y);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                add(x,y);
                break;
            case 2:
                subtract(x,y);
                break;
            case 3:
                divide(x,y);
                break;
            case 4: 
                multiply(x,y);
                break;
            case 5:
                exit(yes);
        }
    }while(yes = false);

    return 0;
}

int showMenu(int &choice){
    cout << "*" << setw(50) << setfill('-') << "*" << endl;
    cout << "*" << setfill(' ') << right << setw(30) << "Calculator" << setw(19) << "*" << endl;
    cout << "*" << setfill ('=') << setw(50) << "*" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ') << "* 1.) Add operation. " <<setw(30) << "*" << endl;
    cout << "* 2.) Subtract operation. " << setw(25) << "*" << endl;
    cout << "* 3.) Divide operation. " << setw(30) << "*" << endl;
    cout << "* 4.) Multiply operation. " << setw(30) << "*" << endl;
    cout << "* 5.) Exit. " << setw(40) << "*" << endl;
    cout << "*" << setfill('-') << setw(50) << "*" << endl;
    cout << "Please choose your option: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if(choice < 0 || choice > 5){
        cin.clear(choice);
        cout << "Invalid selection." << endl;
    }
    return choice;
}

double getX(double &x)
{
    cout << "Input first number: " << endl;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}

double getY(double &y)
{
    cout << "Input second number: " << endl;
    cin >> y;
    return y;
}

int add(double x, double y)
{
    double sum = x+y;
    cout << x << "+" << y << " = " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}

int subtract(double x, double y)
{
    double mus = x-y;
    cout << x << "-" << y << " = " << mus << endl;
    return 0;
}

int multiply(double x, double y)
{
    double product = x*y;
    cout << x << "*" << y << " = " << product << endl;
    return 0;
}

int divide(double x, double y)
{
    double quotient = x/y;
    cout << x << "/" << y << " = " << quotient << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool exit(bool &yes)
{
    cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;
    yes = true;
    return yes;
}
```

Comment: It should be `while (yes == false);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the correct comparison operator , while(yes == false);

Comment: This got the whole thing working, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To compare, `==` is used. The operator `=` is used for assignment. The code in the `do` loop uses the operator `=`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the equator '==' to judge the condition "yes == false", not the assignment operator '='. Because the assignment operator always return true so that 'while(yes = false)' is as same as 'while(1)'.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have a problem with your while loop condition. You are using the bool variable "yes" to finish the loop.

What you probably meant to do was
    `while(yes == false)`

You can avoid this common mistake in this and all of your future codes by inverting the condition check order, like so:

`while(false == yes)`

I know it is kind of counter intuitive to read, but if you happen to miss again the second =
`while(false = yes)`
will never compile and will tell you there is an error in line XYZ which will be easier to debug than an erroneous assignment like the one you have at hand. This I promise will save you endless nights of debugging.